# Auto release/close/dispose mutex after X seconds

Tags: c#, mutex

I have a C# application which wants to raise a flag, valid for X seconds for a VB.NET application to see it and act upon it. So, I'm trying to use a mutex but I'm somehow failing to delete it (release/close/dispose) it after said time. Actually `ReleaseMutex()` throws an exception, because I guess the timer is on a separate thread. So I'm wondering how can I do this? If I comment out `ReleaseMutex()`, the VB.NET sees the mutex as still alive.

C# code:

```
    private static Mutex mutex = null;
    
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            Form myForm = (Form)Application.OpenForms["BrowserWindow"];
            Core.IsUserClosed = false;
            myForm.WindowState = FormWindowState.Minimized;
            myForm.Show();
            myForm.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal;
            myForm.Focus();

            SetTimeout(() =>
            {
                mutex.ReleaseMutex();
                mutex.Close();
                mutex.Dispose();
            }, 5000);
            bool createdNew;
            mutex = new Mutex(false, "mymutex", out createdNew);
        }
        catch (Exception exception1)
        {
            return;
        }
    }
    public void SetTimeout(Action action, int timeout)
    {
        var timer = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer();
        timer.Interval = timeout;
        timer.Tick += delegate (object sender, EventArgs args)
        {
            action();
            timer.Stop();
        };
        timer.Start();
    }
```

VB.NET code:

```
    Dim bConnected As Boolean = False
    Try
        Dim mutex As Mutex
        mutex = Mutex.OpenExisting("mymutex")
        bConnected = True
    Catch ex As WaitHandleCannotBeOpenedException
        MsgBox("Mutex does not exist.")
    Catch ex As UnauthorizedAccessException
        MsgBox("Unauthorized access: " & ex.Message)
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.ToString)
    End Try
    MsgBox(bConnected)
```

Comment: What exception is it throwing, exactly?

Comment: @MatthewWatson Invoke or BeginInvoke cannot be called on a control until the window handle has been created.

Comment: Your code looks a bit overcomplicated. Where do you stop the timer? The exception is probably thrown after you close `myForm` in whatever way. There could be also a better/simpler solution, try to explain better what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: @Steeeve I am trying to do IPC between a C# and a vb.net app. The C# needs to inform to vb.net app that for the next X seconds, it can do something. So the easiest solution I could think of, is a mutex.

Comment: @MirrorMirror well, many roads lead to Rome ;). Where do you exactly get what exception? I see one possibility: in `SetTimer` you are restarting the timer. To what form belongs your `button1_click` event handler? Can it get closed in the X seconds by the user or by code?

Comment: @Steeeve I solved the problem by running `mutex.WaitOne()` before `ReleaseMutex`. It does not crash any more.